# Definite Integration problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was working on a small Integration problem, where i was needed to solve another integral:

$$I= \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{1+\cos^2x} dx $$

Working:

$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{1+\cos^2x} dx=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sec^2x}{\sec^2x+1} dx$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sec^2x}{2+\tan^2x} dx$$

Substituting, $\tan x=t, \sec^2x dx=dt$

$$\implies \frac{\sec^2x}{2+\tan^2x}dx=\frac{dt}{2+t^2}$$
which gives us $$I= \left[
      \begin{array}{cc|c}{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\tan^{-1}\frac{\tan x}{\sqrt2}}
      \end{array}
    \right]_0^\pi$$
I think the answer should be zero. After seeing the answer at [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201/%281%2bcos%5E2x%29%20from%200%20to%20pi), i think i am doing a serious mistake. Ay help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your major mistake is integrating right through a singularity.

Comment: It was solved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/639378/85343)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
I&=\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd x \over 1 + \cos^2\pars{x}}}=
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over 1 + \sin^{2}\pars{x}}
=
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over 1 + \bracks{1 - \cos\pars{2x}}/2}
\\[3mm]&=
2\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd x \over 3 - \cos\pars{x}}
=2\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over 3 - \pars{1 - t^{2}}/\pars{1 + t^{2}}}
\,{2\,\dd t \over 1 + t^{2}}
=4\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over 4t^{2} + 2}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\root{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{\root{2}t}^{2} + 1}\,\root{2}\,\dd t
=\color{#00f}{\large{\root{2} \over 2}\,\pi}
\end{align}
where $\ds{t \equiv \tan\pars{x \over 2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Is $t = \tan x$ a valid substitution, in the given range: $[0, \pi]$? Is it continuous in that interval?

Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_single_variable). That'll show you what's *wrong* with your method. The correct way is as suggested by Yiorgos.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. First observe that

$$I= \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{1+\cos^2x} dx =
2\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1+\cos^2x} dx,
$$
and then carry out your transformation.